# What happens on hardware when running a parallel program

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu-cores

For example, a machine has two processors and each processor has two cores. I write a parallel program by using OpenMP and run it with 3 threads. What happens on the hardware? I think only one processor will deal with the program (is that right?) but I can't image how are the three threads distributed to two cores.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to answer your question in the scope of a SO "answer" - you will need to read up on implementation of parallel processing for the particular architecture of your machine if you want the "real" answer. Short answer is "it depends". But your program could be running on both processors, on any or all of the four cores; they key to understand here is that you can control that to some extent with the structure of your program, but the neat thing about OMP is that usually "you ought not to care". If threads are operating concurrently, they will usually get a core each; but if they need to access the same memory space that may slow you down since "short term data" likes to live in the processor's (core's) cache, and that means there is a lot of shuffling data going on. You get the greatest performance improvements if different threads DON'T have to share memory.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused how both of the two processors may have copies of the program. Could you recommend some articles or books for me? Thanks!

Comment: Most instructions "live in memory". In a multi threaded program, the dispatcher instructs "core 2 of processor 3, go do the instructions stored starting at `0x00123400`. A millisecond later it might say "that's enough for now, store your state so far and go do this other thing". No immediate recommendations of books spring to mind sorry.

Comment: Hi @Floris, in my understanding, if there are communications between processors(not cores here, let's assume cores are inside processors), the program must be written with MPI. What if I only use OpenMP to write the program? The system allocate the job to only one processor or to several different processors? I think each processor has its own memory and they also have a shared memory and I don't think processors need to use shared memory to deal with ONLY  OpenMP program. I'm not quite sure about it anyway...

Comment: Programs written with OMP can use all cores on all processors.